# Why was my 2016 MacBook Pro keyboard illuminated when I woke up?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, camera, power-management

MBP wasn't plugged into anything and isn't scheduled to wake up, the laptop was flipped in the open position all night. When I glanced at it at ~8am the keyboard was illuminated. I didn't touch it.

Did the camera sense movement which caused the laptop to wake up?

Comment: It's probably a bug with the new hardware. Mine's keyboards sometimes is kept lit even when the lid is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haven't had this issue again. must have just been a bug.